# Loading a class based on a level/stage?

Tags: java, android, class

I have come across a bit of a problem. I have a class called "GameScreen" which will know what level and stage has been selected. From that I can build a string to suggest something like "level1_1" or "level1_2". The problem is how do I load this class now?

I was going to use `Class.forname(string)` however each level is a different class so how do I pass the new operator to the class?

I am trying to achieve something like this... `world = new World(worldListener);` where "World" is the class such as "level1_1".

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: doesn't make sense... are you asking about reflection?

Comment: Yeah, If I use  Class c = Class.forName("java.lang.String"); how would I allow this to be created as "new" so it will not cause a null pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact that there are much better ways to implement this (see the other answers, for example), this *should* work (not tested, ignores exceptions, may cause abdominal distention, etc.):

```
public World createWorld(String levelClassName, WorldListener listener) throws Exception
{
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(name);
    Constructor<World> ctor = (Constructor<World>) clazz.getConstructor(WorldListener.class);
    World world = ctor.newInstance(listener);

    return world;
}
```

Comment: Seriously, though, there are **much** better ways to design this.

Comment: Thanks that works great, I can understand the abstracting way but I cant see a way around the whole "1_1" or "1_2" class parameters.

Comment: Would it just be better to create a "LevelManager" class that takes the stage and level and then calls the appropriate method within its own methods?

Comment: Consider [a more object-oriented representation for your game classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231527/). For Android, [consider making each level an activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548139/android-game-design) - no factory class to worry about at all, then, since Android manages it all for you once you configure the application.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I only have one activity that is started and I have created a screen class which means I dont have to worry with the activity stack.

Answer (score 1):

You must use reflection (java.lang.reflect)

First, even if the class for each level is different, all of them should extend/implement a common superclass/interface so basic operations are available (v.g. a constructor, a startLevel() method, and so on).

With reflection, you can chose the class related to your level, instantiate it, and pass it to your engine so it invokes your class.

As a side note, I find the architecture strange. Unless there is some other reason to do this, I would suggest using a unique class for levels and loading the configuration for each level from files. It may not be suited if gameplay changes between level, though.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). For your case you could implement a CreateLevel(String level)  method which does a simple case-statement to determine which class to create or use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Um... there's 101 better ways of doing that.

**Update** For example:

```
public abstract class Level {
    // or whatever your interface is
    abstract public void createWorld(WorldListener worldListener);
    abstract public void nextWorld();
}

public class Level1 extends Level {
    public void createLevel(WorldListener worldListener) {
        /** do it **/
    }
    public Level nextLevel() { return new Level2(); }
}
```

Then somewhere else:

```
Level cur = new Level1();
do {
    cur.createLevel(worldListener);
    ...
    cur = cur.nextLevel();
} while (cur != null);
```

**Original**
For example:

```
public abstract class Level {
    final public int number;
    public Level(int num) { this.number = num; levels[num-1] = this;/* set up level */ }

    // adjust 10 to number of levels
    static private Level[] = new Level[10];
    static public getLevel(int num) { return levels[num-1]; }

    // or whatever your interface is
    abstract public void createWorld(WorldListener worldListener);
}

public class Level1 extends Level {
    public Level1() { super(0); }
    public void createWorld(WorldListener worldListener) {
        /** do it **/
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else:

```
Level.getLevel(1).createWorld();
```

Comment: I dont understand how that will work because of the abstract class. It is a better way of doing it but by calling Level.getLevel(1).createLevel() will that not throw an error because I have tried to declare an abstract class?

Comment: @Chris: no, because getLevel(1) returned a Level1 instant.

Comment: The same problem remains though, you still have to say "= new Levelx" this app is setup to be deterministic so every level class will setup the stage different. Each Level will have a ".createlevel" field but its how to actually say "load level 1, stage 4" for instance this example would be "Level cur = new Level1_1();